# Is there a delay between when a SurveyMonkey survey response is submitted and when it becomes available in the API?

Tags: delay, timing, surveymonkey

We have written an import process that runs at night and uses the Survey Monkey API to pull in all survey responses submitted since the last time the import process ran, minus 1 hour. So usually it runs at 11 p.m. Eastern (4 a.m. UTC), and grabs all survey responses with a start_modified_at = the previous day at 10 p.m. Eastern (3 a.m. UTC). So for example, if our process ran at 11 p.m. Eastern on 01/11/2017, it would grab all survey responses modified between 10 p.m. Eastern on 01/10/2017 and 11 p.m. Eastern on 01/11/2017. Then when our process is done, it writes its last run time minus 1 hour (10 p.m. Eastern) to a database, so the next day it starts pulling from that time.

What we're seeing is we're missing some survey responses. It seems that survey responses submitted after sometime around 7 p.m. Eastern on the date when our process runs aren't available (don't come back in the API calls) at 11 p.m. Eastern when our process runs. Then we write the last run time to 10 p.m., meaning the following night we will miss surveys submitted between 7 p.m. Eastern and 10 p.m. Eastern the previous day. If we later (the next day after our import process runs) set our last run time to before the time when the missed surveys were submitted, and re-run the import process, we pick them up.

So it seems that there is some kind of delay after around 7 p.m. Eastern, when survey responses submitted during that time aren't immediately available in the Survey Monkey API, and aren't available for several hours. Perhaps there is some kind of batch process running on the Survey Monkey side at 7 p.m. Eastern that is delaying these responses from being immediately available? Perhaps there is always a 4 hour delay between when a response is submitted and when it's available in the API, and since we run at 11 p.m. Eastern that means we're missing anything submitted within 4 hours before that?

In any case, we can make sure we pickup these surveys by modifying our import process to check for everything 25 hours before its last run instead of just 1 hour before its last run. However, I am curious why the delay is happening.

Thank you.

Comment: I ran our import process in our test environment against all of our survey responses since 01/2014 to see what all has been missed. Looks like this problem first started happening in 09/2016, when we started using version 3 of the SurveyMonkey API.

Comment: no responses should be available immediately. You should contact SurveyMonkey support about that, seems to be an issue with date filtering. What is the exact filter you use? something like `date_created_start=2017-01-12T22:00:00-05:00` if so there's a bug with timezone offset that has a fix going out soon (today, potentially), setting `date_created_start=2017-01-13T03:00:00` for 10pm EST shouldn't have the issue.

Comment: Our filter is start_modified_at=2016-09-02T02:00:00. We use Java to convert our Eastern timestamp into UTC, so there's no need to add or subtract when we pass it into the webservice.

Even if there was some kind of issue with the timestamp offset, we're trying to grab all of the surveys submitted in the 25 hours before our run, and the ones that we're missing were submitted in the 4 hours before our run. I would think if we had a problem with timestamp offsets we would be missing surveys closer to the 25 hours-ago mark, where our filter is starting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question belongs in the SurveyMonkey help forum